# why is spring boot's DataJpaTest scanning @Component

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Confident this hasn't been asked but reading through the Spring docs and testing utilities I found this [annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test) and thought I'd start using it. Reading through the fine print I read:

Regular @Component beans will not be loaded into the ApplicationContext.

That sounded good and I even liked the idea of using H2 except from what I found the entity I wanted to use had catalog and schema modifiers to it and the default H2 I couldn't figure out how to support that. I made an H2 datasource for the test branch and use that and override the replace. I wound up with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ABCH2Congfiguration.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class StatusRepositoryTest {

}
```

However my tests fails fro Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type. 
which leads to: 
Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency.

However the customerServiceImpl is this bean:

```
@Component
public class CustomerServiceImpl  implements CustomerService {
}
```

That says @Component. The fine print for DataJpaTest says it doesn't load @Components. Why is it doing that and thus failing the test?

As Kyle and Eugene asked below here's the rest:

```
package com.xxx.abc.triage;
@Component
public interface CustomerService {
}

Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xxx.abc")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xxx.abc")
//@Profile("h2")
public class ABMH2Congfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "h2source")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabase build = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).setName("ABC").addScript("init.sql").build();
        return build;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter bean = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        bean.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        bean.setShowSql(true);
        bean.setGenerateDdl(true);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        bean.setPackagesToScan("com.xxx.abc");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

}
```

And just to clarify the question, why is @Component being loaded into the context within a @DataJpaTest?

Comment: `@DataJpaTest` is for spring data repositories testing, why you need `@Component` inject to repositories test?

Comment: Eugene, I don't want the component to be loaded in the context and I thought using DataJpaTest would ensure that but that's not what is happening.

Comment: Please, share `ABCH2Congfiguration`

Comment: Also share the `CustomerService` interface.

Comment: @Kyle check it out

Comment: @EugeneUstimenko check it out

Comment: Thinking of putting a little project together and posting it as a bug to spring-boot.

Comment: I believe this is a bug.

Comment: I am having the same problem. A class using `@DataJpaTest` but other Component/Configuration classes are getting loaded magically from libraries on the classpath. There is no way to figure out why! This is why I hate Spring. When it works perfectly, great. When it doesn't ... too bad, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

`@ComponentScan` automatically inject all found `@Component` and `@Service` into context. You could override it by separate `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
CustomerService customerService{
    return null;
}
```

Or remove `@Component` annotation from `CustomerService` and `CustomerServiceImpl`, but you should add `@Bean` at your production `@Configuration`

Answer (score 1):

`@DataJpaTest` does not load `@Component`, `@Service`... by default, only `@Repository` and internal things needed to configure Spring data JPA.

In your test, you can load any `@Configuration` you need, and in your case, you load `@ABMH2Congfiguration` which performs a `@ComponentScan` that's why Spring try to load your `CustomerService`.

You should only scanning the `@Repository` in this configuration class, and scan others `@Component`, `@Service`... in another `@Configuration` like `DomainConfiguration`. It's always a good practice to separate different types of configurations.